# Using mod_rewrite to preserve arguments from referring URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
www.mysite.com/foo/article?id=8888&area=9999
```

On the above page, there are about 20 links. When one of those links are clicked, the user is taken to:

```
    www.mysite.com/foo/a_new_page
```

But what I want to happen (using .htaccess file) is when a link is clicked, the arguments in the referring URL are preserved and appended so clicking the same link would take them to:

```
    www.mysite.com/foo/a_new_page?id=8888
```

But I can't figure it out. I know I need to use QSA to append them and not overwrite anything that may be set. But I can't figure out how to test if an argument exists on the referring URL and append it so the arguments are preserved through the different pages.

Any ideas how?

Comment: What is your current htaccess?

Comment: I've updated my post to include my .htaccess file

Comment: How are you determining the new page? meaning where do you get `/a_new_page` from? You said the user is taken to this page.

Comment: That is just a typical page. Technically they could go anywhere

Comment: What is the link you click already has some query string like: `www.mysite.com/foo/a_new_page?id=11111` What do you want final URL to become?

Comment: That scenario would never happen

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?mysite\.com/.*\?id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^foo(.*)$ foo/$1?id=%2 [L]
```

Comment: I can't get this to work at all. It just takes me to the URL without the arguments appended :/

Comment: @Nadine Are you sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and working? Is htaccess being read and processed? Are you sure you have the right referer?

Comment: See my last edit. I've nearly got your code to work. It now just gices me a redirect. The rewrite works, I just need to resolve the redirect rubbish.

Comment: @Nadine you don't want the `http://www.mysite.com` in the rule. That's causing the redirect. Just `/new_page?id=%2` is good enough.

Comment: @Nadine Also, you need the other condition in my answer, otherwise it will loop. (I had a mistake in it before)